# how to Dynamically bind values in Tree Node in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to dynamically build a list and set it into the tree node. I am trying to loop the data from 2 tabs and trying to set this temp list in tree node. Please share some sample code

**Sample Code**

```
 myfiles: TreeNode[] = [ { data: { name: 'Cloud', size: '20mb', type: 'Folder', },
                children: [ { data: { name: 'backup-1.zip', size: '10mb', type: 'Zip', }, }, { data: { name: 'backup-2.zip', size: '10mb', type: 'Zip', }, },], }, { data: { name: 'Desktop', size: '20mb', type: 'Folder', },
                children: [ { data: { name: 'backup-1.zip', size: '10mb', type: 'Zip', }, }, { data: { name: 'backup-2.zip', size: '10mb', type: 'Zip', }, },], 
                } ];
```

Comment: Sample Code                                                                                                     
myfiles: TreeNode[] = [    {      data: { name: 'Cloud', size: '20mb', type: 'Folder', },
      children: [  { data: { name: 'backup-1.zip', size: '10mb', type: 'Zip', }, },        { data: { name: 'backup-2.zip', size: '10mb', type: 'Zip', }, },],    },    {
      data: { name: 'Desktop', size: '20mb', type: 'Folder', },
      children: [{ data: { name: 'backup-1.zip', size: '10mb', type: 'Zip', }, },  { data: { name: 'backup-2.zip', size: '10mb', type: 'Zip', }, },],    }
  ];

Comment: Please share your code in your question, so that others can help you.